# Is there a common origin to the phrase "the revolution will not be televised / mentioned in the newspaper"

Tags: quote-source, g-k-chesterton

I'm listening in an offhand way to G.K. Chesterton's *Tales from the Long Bow* audiobook and I heard the phrase:

> when the real revolution happens it won't be mentioned in the newspapers

It sounded like something I remembered hearing on community radio a few years ago, and I remembered Gil Scott-Heron's poem ["The revolution will not be televised"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Revolution_Will_Not_Be_Televised)

Is it just a common sentiment or coincidence that these would be so similar or is this a legitimate reference to Chesterton?